# Transparency in C++

Tags: c++, transparency, gdi

I'm trying to create transparency in my application.
For instance the window of my app is square and i want to make it round, by hiding parts of the window.

My code looks something like this:

```
HDC hdcMask = nullptr;
HBITMAP hBMP = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(nullptr, L"C:\\mask.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 150, 160, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SelectObject(hdcMask, hBMP);
HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
HDC hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

TransparentBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, 150, 160, hdcWindow, 0, 0, 150, 160, RGB(0,0,0));
```

where mask.bmp is a bitmap where white is what i want to be transparent and black is what I want to be visible.

After applying this code, nothings happens. What am I doing wrong ? Is there another method to obtain the desired result?

Note: I need this code to work on Windows XP OS or later.

Comment: What do you mean by "or earlier"? Windows 2000? Windows ME? Windows 98? Or did you confuse it with "or later"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of making a window transparent and/or translucent.

[SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145102.aspx) will make parts of a window transparent.

[SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633540.aspx) can make parts of a window transparent, and can also apply translucency to the whole of the rest of the window.

[UpdateLayeredWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633556.aspx) can give individual windows different amounts of translucency.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a different format than bmp where you can also include alpha data?

You can use a PixelFormat32bppPARGB Bitmap, use Bitmap::LockBits an Bitmap::Unlockbits
to keep the file's format and avoid having the alpha setting overwritten.

Comment: i just found this. http://blog.duck17.net/post/Per-pixel-Alpha-Blending-in-Native-Win32-API.aspx    If it doesn't work i'll write you a snippet.